# Bootstrap responsive sidebar resize issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having trouble with my responsive sidebar. I want the sidebar not to change its size when you resize the window. It should still collapse when the screen gets too small though.

I tried setting min-width, but that messed everything up even more. This jsfiddle is the default sidebar with no changes made by me.

```
.affix-sidebar{
    padding-right:0; 
    font-size:small;
    padding-left: 0;
    min-width: Xpx;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gn2TY

Also, in some cases the content doesn't seem to resize properly, it gets out of screen.

Hopefully someone can give me some advice with this one.

Comment: why are you using min-width and not width? try setting `width:200px` and in the responsive style `width: auto`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gn2TY/1/ that didn't solve the problem, unless I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the basis for a fixed size navigation on the side

```
.sidebar {
    width: 190px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
}

.main-content {
    margin-left: 190px;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    background:red
}
```

The issue with your code is that you are using the responsive grid for both your navigation and content, you probably just want to use columns inside the main-content wrapper

http://jsfiddle.net/JL626/

Comment: I have no idea to be honest, could help me a little bit more by providing me an example based on my jsfiddle?